# R - How to extract file from directory based on user input

Tags: regex, r, pattern-matching

I am relatively new to R and struggling with file extraction.
I have a list of CSV files (i.e. `001.csv`, `002.csv`, ....) in my directory `xyz` and need to extract a specific file based on the input given by user.
User input is in the form of `1`, `2` ... (stored in `y`) which I tried converting by leading 0's.

When I run the code

```
filename = as.character(formatC(y, width=3, flag=0))

list.files(directory,pattern = "^",filename,"\\.csv$")
```

I get the result

```
character[0]
```

which implies my pattern code is incorrect, I want the file for eg: `001.csv` to be extracted

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Try `files <- list.files(directory, pattern = paste0("^", filename, ".*\\.csv$"))`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you miss the pattern that will match any file that starts with the `filename` then can match any 0+ characters and ends with `.csv`.

To build it, use `paste0`:

```
files <- list.files(directory, pattern = paste0("^", filename, ".*\\.csv$"))
```

Where:

- `"^"` - start of the file name string
- `filename` - the filename you pass
- `".*\\.csv$"` - any 0+ characters (`.*`) followed by `.csv` (`\\.csv`) at the end of the string (`$`).

Answer (score 0):

> `filename = as.character(formatC(y, width=3, flag=0))`

The `formatC` flag `0` seems to work only for numerical objects; if you read the user input `y` with e. g. `y = readline()`, `y` is of type "character". You get the desired formatting with

```
filename = formatC(as.integer(y), width=3, flag=0)
```

(`as.character()` isn't needed because the `formatC()` value already has that type).

> `list.files(directory,pattern = "^",filename,"\\.csv$")`

This isn't a correct usage of

```
 list.files(path = ".", pattern = NULL, all.files = FALSE,
            full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE,
            ignore.case = FALSE)
```

- surely you meant to concatenate `"^"`, `filename` and `"\\.csv$"`.

All told I suggest to build the whole filename pattern with `sprintf()`, i. e.:

```
filename = sprintf("%03d\\.csv", as.integer(y))
list.files(directory, filename)
```